# count houshold income using R

Tags: r, database, variables, var

I have this data frame where I should count for each household how much monetary support they should get;

My data looks like this:

| hh_id | gender | hh_income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | 563 |
| 1 | H | 563 |
| 1 | H | 563 |
| 2 | F | 0 |
| 2 | F | 0 |
| 2 | F | 0 |
| 3 | H | 0 |
| 3 | F | 0 |

Those with the same hh_id are from the same household;

If hh_icome == 0; I should count how many people are in that household and multiply that number by 175$ and that is the hh_income for that hh.

Example: the hh with the Id == 2 has the income of 0; have 3 individuals so The income should change from 0 to 3*175=525; so the data for that he would look like this:

| hh_id | gender | hh_income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | F | 525 |
| 2 | F | 525 |
| 2 | F | 525 |

any ideas please;

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(hh_id) %>% 
  mutate(hh_income = case_when(hh_income == 0 ~ n() * 175, 
                               TRUE ~ hh_income))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   hh_id [3]
  hh_id gender hh_income
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 F            563
2     1 H            563
3     1 H            563
4     2 F            525
5     2 F            525
6     2 F            525
7     3 H            350
8     3 F            350
```